# Create Multiple Subdags in One DAG

Tags: python, airflow

I have in `main_DAG`, multiple tasks (which are subdags): `subdag1`, `subdag2`, `subdag3`. Whenever I try to create a flow like this:

```
main_DAG>>subdag1>>subdag2>>subdag3
```

I get this error:

```
Tried to set relationships between tasks in more than one DAG: dict_values([<DAG: main_DAG, <DAG: main_DAG.subdag2>])
```

But when I write this:

```
main_DAG>>subdag1>>subdag1>>subdag1
```

I don't get any error. SO, is there any way I can use diferent subdag tasks in the same DAG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write it this way

**main_dag >> [subdag1, subdag2 , subdag3]**

In this way once main_dag completed it will trigger subdag1,subdag2 & subdag3 at once in parellel.

Comment: thanks for answering! but still the same error

Comment: can you share airflow graph screenshot if possible?